# Drawing circuit activity through a D flip-flop while ignoring propagation delay

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, delay

Can someone explain how would would draw the Y and Z activity in the following problem (if we ignore propagation delay and assume Y and Z start at 0)?  How do the clock and X help in this problem?  What exactly is the D flip-flop doing that may change Y and Z, and how can we draw them to show this change?

[image]

Comment: What have you already tried, and why or how didn't it work?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds a little like homework, so I'll just give an idea of how I'd progress:

- First I would work out Y. The D-FF changes it's output to X at the rising edge of the clock input, so you can easily figure out this waveform. For example at the first rising edge, X is at 1 so Y becomes 1 at this point.
- Armed with this info, we simply XOR the X and Y waveforms to produce Z. The truth table for an XOR gate is shown below. The clock line is irrelevant here.

[image: XOR gate and truth table]

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate on the Y part?  I'm primarily confused as to what the D-FF does.  If X is one at any point, what information does this tell us about Y, and similarly, if X is 0 at any point, what does this tell us about Y?

Answer (score 0):

When the clocked pulse is at the rising edge, the value of y is equal to that of x(D), and stays on when the clock pulse falls until another rising edge. Then use the output y and the x  together with the xor table to get z.

Answer (score 0):

I must add to the answers that a D-type FlipFlop is short for "data." These FlipFlops are designed to be very simplistic. The information you wish to be placed at the output is what you place at the input of the device.

i.e., if you want the D FlipFlop to hold a logic HIGH, then place a logic HIGH at its input and clock the device. Changes can only be made to the output of a flip flop once a clock pulse is received.